# Google Play Games leaderboard or sign-in pop-up take a long time to appear?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

The `OnButtonPress()` is called when a button is pressed.

```
void OnButtonPress(){ if(PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.IsAuthenticated())
                         PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ShowLeaderboardUI("Your_leaderboardID");
         else
                         Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success)=>{
                             PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ShowLeaderboardUI("Your_leaderboardID");
                         });}
```

The issue: compared to other games with Google Play Services, the leaderboard or the sign in popup take a long time to appear in my app! How can I fix this? Is it because of my code?

Comment: do you authenticate it when application starts?

Comment: @UmairM No, the code in the question is called when a button is pressed.

Comment: I know! but my question is **do you authenticate GPGS using `Social.localUser.Authenticate()` at start of application?

Comment: @Umair M No. But, I use ` PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();` Please write a full answer :)

Comment: please mark the answer as correct

Comment: Np. it is recommended to authenticate GPGS at start of application. If it still takes same amount of time there might be some other problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Awake()` method of your script call this code:

```
Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {
    // handle success or failure
});
```

This will try to sign in when game starts so won't take extra time in authenticating when you try to show Leaderboard UI. For more info check [Documentation](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! There's a small issue with your code though. If the user doesn't want to sign in, the game will continue asking them everytime the scene is restarted! Can you remedy this?

Comment: That's where you use your programming skills to check if use didn't choose it at first time then do not do it automatically at next time. Give opportunity to sign in manually as well. Check [Sign In Best Practices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPapbl8R9ws&index=2&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIKxwLEpFSWvCgdfEYlBQijk) from Google.